# Can't create Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am having troubles creating a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse. When I go to:

```
File > New > Project... > Web > Dynamic Web Project
```

and then select `Apache Tomcat v7.0` as Target Runtime this error shows up at the top of the window:

```
Runtime "Apache Tomcat v7.0" is invalid
```

Now I will not be able to press on Next or Finish to create the project.

What's wrong? Why does eclipse tell me that tomcat is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do these steps to troubleshoot your issue.

In eclipse go to Windows>Preferences>Server>Run Time Environments.

Now please check following things

1. make sure apache tomcat 7 is there.
2. If this is present make sure that the path specified in "Tomcat installation directory" there is still a tomcat at that path.
3. If above two are good then delete the runtime and re add your tomcat as runtimes.

I hope this helps you fix your problem :).